# How can I render yaml block while converting from docx to markdown in Pandoc

Tags: python, markdown, docx, pandoc

I have some docx documents that contain in the header some yaml information like this

```
---
key: value
---
```

and I am using Pandoc to convert them to markdown using `markdown_mmd`
those values are meant to stay at the markdown, but when I convert them the yaml block gets ignored by Pandoc

Question: How can I preserve the YAML block and render it as it is to the markdown files?

Comment: you mean you have that as text inside the word document as rich text? that won't work... but you can use the `--metadata-file myfile.yaml` option to use an external plain text file..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the following:

```
--standalone -t markdown_mmd+yaml_metadata_block
```

Pandoc includes support for the [`yaml_metadata_block`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) which is included by default for the `markdown` format. However, the documentation specifically notes the following regarding using the extension to generate Markdown output:

> When pandoc is used with [-t markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--to) to create a Markdown
>   document, a YAML metadata block will be produced only if the
>   [-s/--standalone](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--standalone) option is used. All of the metadata will appear
>   in a single block at the beginning of the document.

Therefore, you need to include `--standalone` in your options.

Additionally, as you are using a Markdown variant, you need to confirm that the extension is included for that variant. According to the [list of extensions](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#markdown-variants) supported for each variant, I do not see `yaml_metadata_block` listed under `markdown_mmd`. Therefore, you may need to explicitly [enable the extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions). Like this:

```
-t markdown_mmd+yaml_metadata_block
```

Note: I'm not absolutely sure you need to specifically enable the extension based on the explanation given for the `--standalone` option. And I didn't test it. Therefore, I would suggest trying it both with the extension explicitly enabled and without and see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't work for either, then you may need to use the `markdown` variant and then explicitly enable/disable various extensions to get `markdown_mmd` behavior.